# React google maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-redux, react-map-gl

Could some one let me know how to change the defaultCenter which is coming from the default property. How to change the default property and give the values from the server dynamically.

```javascript
class SimpleMap extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        center: {lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33},
        zoom: 11
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <GoogleMapReact
            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
            defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
            >
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move the  `defaultCenter` from default props to component state.

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props)
    this.state = {
      center: {
        lat: 59.95,
        lng: 30.33
      },
      zoom: 11
    }
  }
```

**render**

```
render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMapReact
       defaultCenter={this.state.center} //access here using state
       defaultZoom={this.state.zoom}
     />);
  }
```

Whenever you want to update `center` and `zoom` value just do state update using `setState` and component will re-render with new uddated value.

**With Redux:**

With redux,this value will come from your component container map via reducer to store.